# BigQuery Standard SQL: how to return the first value of array?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ansi-sql

Small working example

```
SELECT SPLIT("hello::hej::hallo::hoi", "::")
```

returns an array `[hello, hej, hallo, hoi]` where I want to select the first element i.e. `hello`. BG Standard provides no `FIRST`, instead `FIRST_VALUE(..) OVER()` which I cannot get working for this example above, so

**How can I select the first value of array with BigQuery Standard SQL?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think the documentation in BigQuery is pretty good.  You can read about arrays [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays).

You can use either `OFFSET()` or `ORDINAL()`.  The method would be:

```
select array[offset(0)]
```

or

```
select array[ordinal(1)]
```

Comment: @JervisChionh . . . The answer is not appropriate for a comment.  It requires unnesting and recreating the array.

Answer (score 7):

If you have NULL values

```
  select array[safe_offset(0)]
```